# Слияние DBF файлов

Tags: dbf, foxpro

Имеется два DBF файла, в одном например 100 записей, в другом 200. Оба файла нужно слить в один, так, чтобы остались только уникальные записи
Пробовал следующий код, но VFP выдает ошибку "function name is missing )"

```
SELECT * FROM 123pf WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test WHERE test.pole == 123pf.pole) INSERT INTO new
```